Bit array for thread synchronization
i'm writing a concurrent implementation of the pageranking algorithm. I got some matrix market files that represent graphs, and i want to traspose the graphs from the file using a struct;
The struct is defined as such:
typedef struct{
int N;
int *out; //array of ints
inmap **in; //array of linked lists pointers
}graph;

For each edge in the file i have to check if it is a duplicate, so i have to access the vertex adjacent list, anche check if i already have the entry, if not i add it. I'm using a method that inserts the key in order to boost insertion performance.
Since I was thinking to adapt the file scan as a producer consumer problem: with one thread reading from the file and n threads writing to the graph struct, i needed to synchronize the threads, to prevent inconsistences as such as two threads accessing the same list.
I have some matrix market files with a lot of nodes and number of nodes in the order of 10^6, i wanted to boost concurrency access. So i thought about implementing a bit array that is accessed by threads in mutual exclusion. Each thread that needs to modify a list, marks the corresponding bit in the bit array and accesses the list. If the bit is already marked the thread gets suspended in a condition variable and gets restarted by another thread that exits the entry point (unmarks the bit in the bit array).
I wanted some opinions about how effective is this method in terms of security in accesses and memory consumption. I did some calculations and in a case i had a graph with almost a million nodes, so using a bit array as the one i coded I'm getting valgrind reports of 116KB used for the bit array alone.
Follows the implementation of the bitmap and the entry point:
typedef struct{
    u_int32_t *bit_array;
    int size;
}bitmap;

typedef struct{
    bitmap *bitmap;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
}ENTRY_POINT;

bitmap *bitmap_create(int size){
    if(size<=0)error("[bitmap_create] size must be positive",here);
    
    bitmap *ret = xmalloc(sizeof(bitmap),here);
    ret->size = size;
    
    int num_cells = (size + 31)/31;
    ret->bit_array = calloc(num_cells,sizeof(u_int32_t));
    if(ret->bit_array == NULL){
        xfree(ret,true,here);
        error("[bitmap_create] Memory Insufficient",here);
    }
    return ret;
}

void bitmap_destroy(bitmap *ptr){
    if(ptr == NULL)return;
    xfree(ptr->bit_array,false,here);
    xfree(ptr,false,here);
    return;
}

void bitmap_set(bitmap *bitmap, int pos){
    bitmap->bit_array[pos / 32] |= (1 << (pos % 32)); // Imposta il bit specifico
}

void bitmap_clear(bitmap *bitmap, int pos){
    bitmap->bit_array[pos / 32] &= ~(1 << (pos % 32)); // Cancella il bit specifico
}

int bitmap_test(bitmap *bitmap, int pos){
    return (bitmap->bit_array[pos / 32] >> (pos % 32)) & 1; // Controlla lo stato del bit specifico
}

ENTRY_POINT *entry_point_create(int size){
    ENTRY_POINT *ptr = xmalloc(sizeof(ENTRY_POINT),here);
    ptr->bitmap = bitmap_create(size);
    xpthread_cond_init(&ptr->cond,here);
    xpthread_mutex_init(&ptr->lock,here);
    return ptr;
}

void entry_point_destroy(ENTRY_POINT *ptr){
    if(ptr == NULL)return;
    bitmap_destroy(ptr->bitmap);
    xpthread_cond_destroy(&ptr->cond,here);
    xpthread_mutex_destroy(&ptr->lock,here);
    xfree(ptr,true,here);
}

void entry_point_access(ENTRY_POINT *ptr, int pos){
    if(ptr->bitmap == NULL)error("[entry_point_access] Bad bitmap pointer",here);
    else if(pos < 0 || pos >= ptr->bitmap->size)error("[entry_point_access] position not valid",here);

    xpthread_mutex_lock(&ptr->lock,here);
        while(bitmap_test(ptr->bitmap,pos) == 1){
            xpthread_cond_wait(&ptr->cond,&ptr->lock,here);
        }
        bitmap_set(ptr->bitmap,pos);
    xpthread_mutex_unlock(&ptr->lock,here);
}


void entry_point_release(ENTRY_POINT *ptr, int pos){
    if(ptr->bitmap == NULL)error("[entry_point_release] Bad bitmap pointer",here);
    else if(pos < 0 || pos >= ptr->bitmap->size)error("[entry_point_release] position not valid",here);
    xpthread_mutex_lock(&ptr->lock,here);
        bitmap_clear(ptr->bitmap,pos);
        xpthread_cond_broadcast(&ptr->cond,here);
    xpthread_mutex_unlock(&ptr->lock,here);
}

The functions that start with x are just redefinitions i made to lib functions to handle edge cases.
